# Puppet: Is it possible to remove multiple lines using file_line type?

Tags: puppet, profile

In past times of the company I work for, someone configured many aliases and exports in `/etc/profile`.

Since then we've implemented Puppet and there's a module which manages the application user exports and aliases.

The new module is actually a very simple one... it makes sure that a file called `application_env.sh` resides in `/etc/profile.d/` and basically that's the file which configures the relevant exports and aliases.

I've been given a task to make sure that these exports and aliases are coming from the `application_env.sh` file only and not from `/etc/profile`.

So what I intend to do is to add to the application_env's manifest which currently looks like so:

```
class appuser-env {
  file{ "/etc/profile.d/appuser-env.sh":
    ensure  => "present",
    content => template("appuser-env/appuser-env.sh.erb"),
    mode    => "774",
    require => Class["facts"],
  }
}
```

Another type which looks like so:

```
file_line{ "remove_old_exports_aliases":
  ensure => absent,
  line => ['export ANT_HOME_1_7_0=/appdir/org/apache/ant/1.7.0', 'export ANT_HOME=$ANT_HOME_1_7_0', 'export PATH=$ANT_HOME/bin:$PATH', 'export JAVA_HOME_1_6_0=/appdir/com/sun/jdk', 'export JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME_1_6_0', 'export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH','export ENVIRONMENT_TYPE=prod','export CVS_RSH=${CVS_RSH-ssh}# change default from rsh to ssh for cvs command','export TOMCAT_HOME_6_0_29=/appdir/org/apache/tomcat/6.0.29','export TOMCAT_HOME=$TOMCAT_HOME_6_0_29','export PATH=$PATH:$TOMCAT_HOME/bin','export VOLDEMORT_HOME=/appdir/voldemort-0.80.1/config/test_config3','export LOCATION=nyc'],
  path => '/etc/profile',
}
```

But when I run `puppet agent -t` on the relevant machine, I get the following error:

```
[root@server4 # puppet agent -t
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Info: Caching catalog for server4.company.com
Info: Applying configuration version '1448374061'
Error: /Stage[main]/appuser-env/File_line[remove_old_exports_aliases]: Could not evaluate: private method `chomp' called for #<Array:0x7fba5a3ead20>
Notice: Finished catalog run in 16.90 seconds
[root@server4 ]#
```

Any idea what this error means or how is it done properly?

Comment: It means you provided an array where a string was expected. Just iterate over the array and create a `file_line` resource for each element. Even better, just provide an entire `/etc/profile` file that you want.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that there's no way to do it all in the same resource... so inconvenient...
I thought about providing a `/etc/profile` file myself but I have to know for certain that there's no way to do it in the same resource.

Comment: What's so inconvenient about a `for` loop?

Comment: You're correct. I just thought Puppet would support a multiple file_line option.

Comment: It's not puppet's lack of support, it's the `stdlib` module's lack of support. You can write your own type to support it since the limitation is not in puppet, but that's a lot more work than a `for` loop.

Comment: @jordanm Care to show an example?

Answer (score 1):

Use multiple `file_line` resources, each removing one line:

```
# for all "file_line" resources .
File_line {
  ensure => absent,
  path   => '/etc/profile',
}

file_line {
  'remove_old_exports_aliases':
    line => 'export ANT_HOME_1_7_0=/appdir/org/apache/ant/1.7.0';
  'remove aliases':
    line => 'export ANT_HOME=$ANT_HOME_1_7_0';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
file {
--
----}
file_line{ "remove_old_exports_aliases":
  ensure => absent,
  line => ['export ANT_HOME_1_7_0=/appdir/org/apache/ant/1.7.0'],
  path => '/etc/profile',
}->file_line{ "remove aliases":
  ensure => absent,
  line => ['export ANT_HOME=$ANT_HOME_1_7_0'],
  path => '/etc/profile',
}
```

try if you can put this in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to ensure lines are removed from `/etc/profile`, (the `file_line` resource is really quite horrible for anything advanced), just manage the contents of `/etc/profile` as a whole. That way you know exactly what's in there and you are describing the desired end state of the system rather than having no idea what's in there apart from a few lines you've explicitly tried to remove.